# Antd Countdown not working for a specific date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs, antd

I’m trying to create a component to a specific date using react with antd. Here's my code:

```
import { Statistic, Col, Row } from 'antd';

const { Countdown } = Statistic;
const deadline = Date.parse('2022-12-31') - Date.now();

const Count = () => {
    return (
        <Countdown title="Countdown" value={deadline} format="DD:HH:mm:ss"/>
    )
}
```

The countdown just displays 00:00:00:00 when the timestamp has is a positive number. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is deadline value?

Comment: Deadline value is 21005705996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deadline passed to the `<Countdown>` component must be an absolute value (that is starting from epoch - Jan 1, 1970).

So you need to change it simply to:

```
const deadline = Date.parse('2022-12-31');
```

You can check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ptdtsv?file=demo.js) example for reference.